# Using Frame Dragging to Catch Dark Matter

Tags: gravity, dark-matter

Is it possible to get a really massive osmium planet for its density which has 50 Earth Masses in one Earth radii(Don't want to use more massive objects because it may be harder and require more energy to change its rotation) and make it rotate to the speed of 10% the speed fo light, so the frame dragging will be really strong.

And then dark matter that goes slower when orbiting in one direction will fall inward towards the object, and dark matter that goes faster will escape. So the stuff falling in will get absorbed by the planet and then it may be possible to use this to study dark matter.
Is this a possible method to trap dark matter and study it or would studying still be a problem after containing it because it can't interact with matter well.

Comment: You really do like Osmium planets don't you?

Comment: "So the stuff falling in will get absorbed by the planet..." - how does dark matter get absorbed since it only interacts gravitationally with the osmium ? It will fly through the planet and out the other side since its KE+PE is constant.

Comment: Wouldn't it get absorbed through frame dragging?

Comment: @MiltonTheMeme Not unless the magic pink unicorns eat it up :) In other words, you can't just say "oh, its frame dragging" without doing the mathematics to back that up.

Comment: I mean the frame dragging would technically slow the dark matter and then in theory it is possible to then have a system that is connected to the planet that rotates it faster and faster and then slows it down periodically so it can cause some of the dark matter to settle on the surface or the core. This is because the space-time goes in the opposite direction of some of the dark matter so wouldn't the dark matter slow down?

Comment: So it seems the more fundamental question is, "can frame dragging take orbital energy from an unaccelerated particle?"